# JSON data into php

Tags: php, json

On my Linux box I use a command:

```
lightning-cli getinfo
```

which gives me then JSON data.

I tried to use:

```
$jsonFile = "sh /bin/lightning-cli getinfo";
$jsondata = file_get_contents($jsonFile);
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
```

which gives me then:
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(sh /bin/lightning-cli getinfo): failed to open stream: No such file or directory ...

How can I get the data into php?

Answer (score 1):

Try [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) instead `file_get_contents`

```
$jsonFile = "sh /bin/lightning-cli getinfo";
$jsondata = shell_exec($jsonFile);
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
```

**OR**

Direct Call

```
 $jsonFile = "lightning-cli getinfo";
 $jsondata = shell_exec($jsonFile);
 $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
```